# how can i save JWT tokens in javafx & java for windows application

Tags: java, javafx

i was looking on google and i couldn't find the answer.
how can i save JWT tokens in javafx and java.
any links and useful answers will be great.

thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of authentication using JWT tokens in Java alongside Spring Boot.

http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/